# How can I safely revert to earlier version of CiviCRM without reverting the database?

Tags: drupal, database

I am using Drupal 7.64. Everything was working fine on my site with CiviCRM 5.10.2.

I upgraded to 5.10.3 and two days later discovered that it broke an event registration page that relies on the extension Group-Based Pricing. Yes, I know that extension is not cleared for takeoff with this version of CiviCRM, but I had tested it carefully before deploying it live, and it has worked for a month. And now I absolutely need to keep using it for the next few months until the event is over.

I then upgraded to 5.10.4 thinking that might fix things. It didn't.

In the meantime, members have made other kinds of contributions, altered their profiles, etc. The database has been changed under 5.10.3 and 4.

So, while I can go back to the 5.10.2 CiviCRM code easily enough, I can't revert the database without losing the changes that were made in the past three days.

What should I do? Can I safely proceed with the upgraded and altered database as is? Is there something I can do to make it safe to use under 5.10.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no database changes between the 5.10 versions so you can switch the code back & forth without issue - however you will lose the security patches, making your site vulnerable - which is not great since the SAs have been published - it might be you do that temporarily but prioritise getting the extension fixed. If you tighten the permission on accessing uploaded files it will mitigate the security issue - does the extension use uploaded files & images?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The extension does not use uploaded files or images. It just allows price sets to show different prices to users in different groups.